# How do I make the profiles for my MongoDB Collection add a new field if the field it's looking for is missing in Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

the very bottom field listed ("dabmeup") is being created correctly along with the other fields if a user that doesn't have a profile, but when a user already has the profile it won't update.
How would I correctly make the code add the field without overwriting what that user already has?
Below is a section my "message.js" file where it checks actually adds the fields.

```
    let profileData;
    try {
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
        if (!profileData) {
            let profile = await profileModel.create({
                userID: message.author.id,
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                coins: 1000,
                bank: 0,
                sent: { type: Number },
                received: { type: Number },
                owner: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 1
                admin: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 1
                nyaw: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 2
                donator: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 3
                dev: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 4
                tester: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 4
                oneK: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 6
                tenK: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 7
                hundK: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 8
                oneM: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 9
                tenM: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 10
                hundM: { type: Number, default: 0 }, //code: 11
                dabmeup: {type: Number, default: 0} //code: 12
            });
            profile.save();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your models if it already defined default 0 so you don't need to add it in `create()` and `save()` is using commit when modify an existing documents.

In summary your code should look like

```js
    let profileData;
    try {
        profileData = await profileModel.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });
        if (!profileData) {
            let profile = await profileModel.create({
                userID: message.author.id,
                serverID: message.guild.id,
                coins: 1000,
                bank: 0,
                sent: 0,
                received: 0,
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

Comment: it still does not update by adding the new field to all the profiles in the collection.

Comment: Sorry you want add new field to collection of mongo or discord.js ?

Comment: I wanted to add a new field to the collection but someone else has already answered me on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a simple script that will iterate through all documents without the `dabmeup` property, and update them all to include it. This only has to be run once.

```js
profileModel.updateMany(
  { dabmeup: { $exists: false } }, // the $exists operator checks if a field exists
  { $set: { dabmeup: 1 } } // the $set operator will set a field without modifying the rest of the document
);
```